# CSP in Keycloak

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-angular

I have a problem with CSP in keycloak. Whenever i set it,it still response me with
frame-ancestors 'self'.

Hello. I am using keycloak-angular library, and i wanted to set checkLoginIframe to true. However i get the error: Refused to frame '...' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'". I had set frame-ancestor to my domain value but it still gives me on endpoint
/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html the cookie with value "frame-ancestors 'self'".